# Estimate gradient of a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}:= \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2<1\}$ , $S$ is open and $\mathbb{\bar{D}}\subset S$. Let $F:S\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $|F(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{D}$. Prove that there exists $\theta \in S$ such that  $|\triangledown F(\theta )| < 4$.

I think it may be easier to solve if it is continuously differentiable. In this condition, $\triangledown F(x)$ can be seen as a $C^1$ vector field and I can find a integral curve originated from $(0,0)$.

When it is differentiable, what I know is only "The differential mean value theorem": $F(y)-F(x)=\triangledown F(\xi )\cdot (y-x)$ . It is hard to consider directions of these two vectors.

Comment: Do you have a source for this problem?

Comment: My classmates and I discussed about this question but do not find the way. I do not know where it comes from.

Comment: Is it really $\theta\in S$? Why not $\theta\in\mathbb{D}$? As a matter of fact, we do not know the size of $F(x)$ for $x\notin\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: If $\theta \in \mathbb{D}$ then naturally $\theta \in S$, I think $\theta $ should be in $\mathbb{D}$